# A minor bug, when editing a post, after clicking on the "edit tags" hoverlink

Tags: bug, edits, 10k-tools, inline-editor, inline-tag-editor

Steps to reproduce:

1. Acquire at least 10,000 reputation to gain access to [inline tag editor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).
2. While the inline tag editor is still open, notice another mistake in the post above and click the edit post button (present right next to the share button).
3. You'll be redirected to edit page (`/posts/{id}/edit`) while completely ignoring the fact that you also have the privilege to [edit posts inline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) (earned long ago at 2,000 reputation). **This is bug #1.**
4. **Bug #2** is that when I submit my edit from the edit page (`/posts/{id}/edit`) and am redirected back to the question page, my edit isn't immediately visible.

This happened on the past 3 out of 10 edits, so it might be a caching issue; but still worth a look!

Comment: reproduced 01, norepro 02

Comment: Which browser are you using? (It's one of the [supported ones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/152515), right?)